# Configure server PHP to handle POST requests

Tags: php, json, post, server

I'm trying to write a PHP script to handle POST requests. Eventually, it needs to take in JSON and write it out to a file. Right now, I'm just trying to get anything to work when I call the public URL.

```
<?php

item1 = $_GET['username'];

    echo $item1;

fopen('TESTER_FILE.txt', 'w');

?>
```

I'm testing it with

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://*********.com/file.php
```

It seems to go through and doesn't throw any errors, but nothing happens. I get no echo or file creation.

Comment: Try `$_POST['username']`

Comment: Made the change, but still nothing

Comment: I don't know the tool you're invoking whith `curl -H "Content-Type: ...`, but it seems that it calls the url with _POST_ data, while your PHP script looks for _GET_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item1 = $_GET['username'];
```

1: You need a `$` prefix to say it's a variable

2: If you expect posted data, use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`

E.g:

```
$item1 = $_POST['username'];
```

---

```
fopen('TESTER_FILE.txt', 'w');
```

This only opens the file for writing, it doesn't actually write anything. For the sake of simplicity, try using [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) instead:

```
file_put_contents('TESTER_FILE.txt', $item1);
```

If you want to append rather than overwrite:

```
file_put_contents('TESTER_FILE.txt', $item1, FILE_APPEND);
```

---

> It seems to go through and doesn't throw any errors, but nothing happens. I get no echo or file creation.

Since you are *trying* to do both of those things, the chances are that you've got an error somewhere and it's being hidden (it's probably the missing `$` on line 3!!).

**Enable error reporting!**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// do the rest of your stuff
```

Comment: but apart form this your doing great ;)